# How to use jpa or hibernate to prevent the deletion of the table

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

i have archive table that i don't want to be deleted so how to use jpa or hibernate to prevent the deletion of the table (delete method must throw an error), or when deleting actually do update (state = deleted). Is there any annotation or any technique to do so?

Comment: Would be very easy with a trigger in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use entity callback @PreRemove and throw runtime exception.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html

Comment: Thank you! this is easy and perfectly suitable for my problem

Answer (score 0):

The `@SqlDelete` annotation allows you to override the default `DELETE` statement executed by Hibernate, so we substitute an `UPDATE` statement instead. Therefore, removing an entity will end up updating the deleted column to true

```
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE tag SET deleted = true WHERE id = ?")

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    private boolean deleted;
}

@Entity(name = "Tag")
@Table(name = "tag")
@SQLDelete(sql =
    "UPDATE tag " +
    "SET deleted = true " +
    "WHERE id = ?")
public class Tag extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```